# html 5 canvas does not work

Tags: html, canvas

I'm newbie to html5, and now I got a problem with canvas. I try to draw a rectangular using canvas 2d. in the developer tool, it displays that canvas is null.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Canvas Testing</title>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var cxt=c.getContext("2d");
    cxt.fillStyle="#FF0000";
    cxt.fillRect(0,0,150,75);

</script>

<style type="text/css">
    body{
        background:#ccc;
        color:777;
        font-size:14px;
        font-family: verdana;
    }
    #myCanvas{
        margin:50px auto;
        background:#eee;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" height="180" width="360"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to place your JavaScript within a function that's called by the `window.onload` event.

```
window.onload = function() {
    var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var cxt=c.getContext("2d");
    cxt.fillStyle="#FF0000";
    cxt.fillRect(0,0,150,75);
}
```

Comment: I tried placing javascript at the bottom of the page, and it works the same. Thanks guy...

Comment: Placing at the bottom as you say will work, using the window.onload as well.A thing to consider though when seting the a onload is that it can be overloaded by other scripts and might give unexpected errors with other scripts. What I do when I use canvases I call an onload function in the body tag:
    <body onload="init()">
that function will be called when the whole body including its elements (in this case the canvas) is loaded and declared. 
A javascript code that is not called in a function can only work with elements that is declared before the script and therefore your canvas is null.

Answer (score 3):

Your JS is running before the document is initialized.